# Cant resolve "Error in function in R when using ggmap

Tags: function, numbers, arguments, rows, ggmap

I am trying to map clusters on a real map from google map but receiving the following issue:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

```
#cleaning of the data sets

aboutProperty1$neighbourhood_group <- NULL

#checking for missing vlaues
is.na(aboutProperty1$price)
is.na(aboutProperty1$minimum_nights)
is.na(aboutProperty1$number_of_reviews)
is.na(aboutProperty1$reviews_per_month)
# missing valeus found in reviews per month, therefore refil themwith average/mean
aboutProperty1$reviews_per_month[is.na(aboutProperty1$reviews_per_month)] <- mean(aboutProperty$reviews_per_month, na.rm=TRUE)
is.na(aboutProperty1$reviews_per_month)

is.na(aboutProperty1$calculated_host_listings_count)
is.na(aboutProperty1$availability_365)

#k means
set.seed(20)
clusters <- kmeans(aboutProperty1[,14:15], 4)
aboutProperty1$Borough <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)
str(clusters)

#plot to visualize the data and the results of the k-means clustering
install.packages("ggmap")
library("ggmap")
register_google(key = "AIzaSyB3NiYj9DJfFuSVC2YTm_EolGO_MafBf8Y")
has_google_account()
DublinMap <- get_map("Dublin", zoom = 10)

ggmap(DublinMap) + geom_point(aes(x = LON, y = LAT, 
color = factor(Borough)), data = aboutProperty1) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Dublin map with clusters",
                     values = c(`1`="yellow",
                                `2`="orange",
                                `3`="red",
                                `4`="green"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. cold you post a [mcve] that gives this error ?

Comment: set.seed(20)
   clusters <- kmeans(aboutProperty[,14:15], 4)
     aboutProperty$Borough <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)
      str(clusters)

install.packages("ggmap")
   library("ggmap")
    register_google(key = "AIzaSyB3NiYj9DJfFuSVC2YTm_EolGO_MafBf8Y")
    has_google_account()
     DublinMap <- get_map("Dublin", zoom = 10)


ggmap(DublinMap) + geom_point(aes(x = Lon[], y = Lat[], 
colour = as.factor(Borough)), data = aboutProperty) + ggtitle("Dublin Boroughs using KMean")

Thanks

Comment: please [edit] your question to add the code rather than adding it to the comments. See [ask]